# How to use global variable in web2py?

Tags: html, image, global-variables, user-input, web2py

I tried to create a global variable called temp in web2py, but apparently the value of the variable doesn't change even if I try to store the user input to temp. It just stays the same (temp = 0.0). What's wrong?

Here is the default.py: http://pastebin.com/dafZZjJx
Here is the index.html: pastebin.com/Lw21Gg15

Is there any other way to send user input to functions when creating images to HTML page? I have used the following line
image=URL(r=request,f='nonhomog_plot')
to make the image but what is the correct syntax, if I want to send the user input to nonhomog_plot without using a global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use globals in web2py, but they're not persistent. You could store temp in session if you like. (BTW, there's no need to declare a global in a context where you're only reading it.)

Alternatively, pass it in your URL's query string:

`image = URL('nonhomog_plot', vars=dict(nu=str(value)))`

or in your case, since you're receiving nu in vars already:

`image = URL('nonhomog_plot', vars=request.vars)`

or to include only nu:

`image = URL('nonhomog_plot', vars=dict(nu=request.vars.nu))`

Comment: Thanks! The following is how I changed it. (I removed the temp variable from the beginning of the program.)  
def index():
    form=...
    image=None
    image2=None
    if form.accepts(request.vars, session):
        session.flash = ...
        session.temp=float(request.vars.nu)
        response.flash = session.temp
        image=URL(r=request,f='nonhomog_plot')
        image2=...
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = ...
    else:
        response.flash = ...
    return dict(form=form, image=image, image2=image2)

def nonhomog_plot():
    return nonhomog(session.temp)

Answer (score 0):

There are no global variables in web2py. You can use cache.ram